# Mysterious error message regarding missing reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdftex

At the very end of my `pdflatex` compilation, I get the following error messages:

```
(see the transcript file for additional information)pdfTeX warning (dest): name
{theorem.10.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{theorem.6.1} has been referenced but does not exist
, replaced by a fixed one
```

And yet there are no `undefined reference` errors.  The problem may be related to the `hyperref` package, but I am not certain of that.

Can someone offer advice or explanation?

Code snippet:

```
\begin{theorem}[Type Safety]
\thmlabel{ssds}{safety} \\[-2ex]
\noindent\begin{enumerate}
 \item{} If $ \IsOf{e}{\tau}$ and $e\StepsTo e'$, then $ \IsOf{e'}{\tau}$.      
 \item{} If $\IsOf{e}{\tau}$, then either $\IsVal{e}$, or there exists $e'$ such that $e\StepsTo e'$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: This should not affect the visible reference, but the hyperlinking will be problematic. If you have a reference to Theorem 10.2 or Theorem 6.1 and you click on it, you may see that the PDF view changes to the first or some full page (since the destination is unknown/replaced by a fixed one). This typically happens when you fiddle around with the counters... are you doing such a thing?

Comment: It can also happen with `\includepdf` from `pdfpages`.

Comment: Well, we are certainly short on information. I think that you should build a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), then it will very likely turn out where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem is definitely with `hyperref`; as suggested, clicking on the reference leads me to the title page of the book.  Yet there are hundreds and hundreds of exactly similar cross-references that work just fine and that do not generate errors!  It's not at all obvious what is special about the two that create the problem.  Any suggestions for how to track that down?

Comment: The problem is with referring to a theorem whose statement consists of an enumeration.  This confuses `hyperref` for some reason.  The solution is to ensure that the enumeration begins on a new line, by inserting, for example, `\ \\[-2ex]` after the theorem title.  Perhaps there are other work-arounds as well.

Comment: For the sake of documenting the issue, I am not "fiddling around with counters" afaik, so this is not likely to be the source of the problem.

Comment: Could you update your question with content that can replicate the problem and is small enough to copy-and-paste and compile?

Comment: @BobHarper I tried with a theorem starting with `enumerate` and had no problem. Without an example it's impossible to help.

Comment: The exact code is

\begin{theorem}[Type Safety]
\thmlabel{ssds}{safety}
\ \\[-2ex]\noindent
\begin{enumerate}
\item{} If $ \IsOf{e}{\tau}$ and $e\StepsTo e'$, then $ \IsOf{e'}{\tau}$.
\item{} If $\IsOf{e}{\tau}$, then either $\IsVal{e}$, or there exists $e'$ such
  that $e\StepsTo e'$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

If I omit the line break, I get the error.  \thmlabel{ch}{th} expands to \label{chap:ch:theorem:th}.

Comment: Bob: Are you still looking for a solution to this? By the way, it is always best if examples are complete, i.e. starting with `\documentclass`, having the necessary packages (but not more), ending with `\end{document}`. Basically, one should be able to copy the code and compile it directly.

Comment: Thank you for asking; I've given up.  It's a 600+ page book.  Tracking it down seems more trouble than it's worth!